# ProgrammingError: column "xxxxx" of relation "xxxx" does not exist

Tags: python, xml, database, psycopg2, odoo

I am using Openerp6.0 and I get the following error whenever i add a custom field in my openerp modules. Why does this error occurs..can anyone please help me??

for example:

```
ProgrammingError: column "x_brand" of relation "res_partner" does not exist
LINE 1: ...comment","website","lang","section_id","supplier","x_brand",...
```

Comment: Please provide more detail about what you were doing when the error occurred.

Comment: i added a new field x_brand in the partner.py file and its corresponding view file.then i updated the modules using     ./openerp-server.py -d database_name -u module_name.when i logged into openerp inteface and oppened customer form and added a test customer and tried to save it.but then it showed the above error.

Comment: can u post your py file code ?
how you add the new custom field ?

Comment: i added x_brand field to .py file like this:                   'x_brand': fields.char('Brand Name',size=64),

Comment: i mean How you inherit res.partner Class ?

Answer (score 2):

For `res.partner`, have you tried updating `base` module from admin>modules?

Comment: wont this command :./openerp-server.py -d database_name -u module_name do update base module too?

Comment: it should,try updating from within modules menu for sake of trying.if it help let me know

Comment: so i should do both?run this command: ./openerp-server.py -d database_name -u module_name and then go update module list?

Comment: ok, 1st)edit code in addons 2nd)simply restart openerp server 3rd)go to openerp modules list 4th)search for base 5th)upgrade module

Comment: this is what i usually do for my own modules